# Instagram profile_picture secure url

Tags: instagram

I'm building up a mash up retrieving by api

calls the feed from instagram/twitter/facebook

api by hashtag.

I don't have any problems to get a secure url

for the profile picture for twitter and

facebook but for instagram I do.

I tried with:

*http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_251686283_75sq_1352714126.jpg
https://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_251686283_75sq_1352714126.jpg*

but it doesn't work :(

**UPDATE**
I do an api call with

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/mycoolhashtag/media/recent?count=100&access_token=my_access_token
```

I get

```
http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_251686283_75sq_1352714126.jpg
```

but I need a secure url and this

```
https://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_251686283_75sq_1352714126.jpg
```

doesn't work

I need a secure url because all the stuff runs in a facebook app
therefore with a https protocol and I don't find the way to get it !

Answer (score 2):

You can use their S3 bucket - distillery. It's not part of CDN but it will give a valid SSL functions

https://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_183641024_75sq_1372016363.jpg

Comment: Yes I agree it no longer works.  Looks like Instagram closed public access to their S3 bucket.  Funny the distillery bucket is still in their documentation: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: I emailed Instagram a few days ago to inquire about this and thus far I haven't heard back. Would suggest others also contact Instagram about this so they see that there is demand for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the https url of a profile picture, given the http one the API gave you, as follows:

```
profile_picture.sub(%r{http://photos-([a-z]).ak.instagram.com}, 'https://igcdn-photos-\1-a.akamaihd.net')
```

For example:
http://photos-h.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-19/11325003_523023611188279_332538806_a.jpg

gets mapped to:
https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-19/11325003_523023611188279_332538806_a.jpg

Answer (score 2):

As of September 2015, Instagram's `/v1/users/{user-id}` endpoint returns HTTPS URLs by default for the user's `profile_picture`, served from https://scontent.cdninstagram.com. You should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER:** You cannot just decide to start using HTTPS and have everything be made secure if the server at the other end doesn't support it, which, it looks like in this case, Instagram does not (other than account related operations like login & edit profile).

It seems you'll have to find another way from making this call from within your facebook app, which I am not familiar with at all, sorry

**OLD ANSWER:** Not quite sure what you're asking, but when I get data back from Instagram the profile picture is always a **HTTP** URL.

For example:

```
"user": {
        "username": "theserv",
        "website": "",
        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_239265119_75sq_1387243654.jpg",
        "full_name": "Diane Alexandra",
        "bio": "",
        "id": "239265119"
      }
```

Are you saying you can't access either of the URL's that you posted? Both do work for me, but the https gives a warning about non-secure content, understandably

Comment: I've updated the post you agree it wasn't very clear :)